# How do I add an hour to sunset time?

Tags: python, time, timedelta

I've got a Python script running that gets the sunset time, compares it with the time now and turns a light on if it's later.

This gets run via a cron job every 15 minutes between certain times of the day so that it should cover the whole year.

But what I'd like to do is stop it from turning the light on if it's more than, say, 1 hour after sunset.

Why?  I just went to bed at about 7.00pm as I had a migraine.  The lights had come on at sunset.  I turned them off.  15 minutes later, I realised my home automation plans were badly flawed as I was rudely awoken by 2 lights coming on suddenly :)

This is the relevant bit of my code:

```
url = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=51.218675&lng=-1.467375"
response = requests.request("GET", url)
data=response.json() #Getting JSON Data
sunset_time_str=data['results']['sunset'] #Getting the Sunset Time

current_date=datetime.date.today() #Getting Today Date
sunset_time=datetime.datetime.strptime(sunset_time_str,'%I:%M:%S %p') #Converting String time to datetime object so that we can compare it current time
sunset_date_time=datetime.datetime.combine(current_date,sunset_time.time()) #Combine today date and time to single object
current_date_time=datetime.datetime.now()
stop_time = ??????????????????? + timedelta(hours=1)
print (stop_time)
if current_date_time > sunset_date_time:
    #turn the light on
```

It's the bit with the '?' that I'm struggling with.  I've tried sunset_date_time and a few other things but I just get an error (for example):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/libcoap/light.py", line 41, in <module>
    stop_time = sunset_date_time + timedelta(hours=1)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Could someone throw me a lifeline, please.  I've searched but all the examples talk about adding an hour (or whatever) onto the time now, not a different time.

Edit: Adding in imports

```
from pytradfri import Gateway
from pytradfri.api.libcoap_api import APIFactory
from pytradfri.util import load_json, save_json
from time import sleep
import requests
import datetime
import time
import json
import timedelta
```

Comment: It looks like you might have called one of your modules `timedelta`? What are your imports here?

Comment: Yes, I've installed timedelta and imported it.  What I'm not sure about is which of my variables is a variable that supports the notion of having 1 hour added to it.  Are they times, or am I doing something like trying to add 1 hour to "apple"?

Comment: Timedelta is not a function, it's a module. The function would look like "timedelta.timedelta() for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what I needed was this:

```
from pytradfri import Gateway
from pytradfri.api.libcoap_api import APIFactory
from pytradfri.util import load_json, save_json
from time import sleep
import requests
import datetime
import time
import json
from datetime import timedelta #This is the line I was missing

url = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=51.218675&lng=-1.467375"
response = requests.request("GET", url)
data=response.json() #Getting JSON Data
sunset_time_str=data['results']['sunset'] #Getting the Sunset Time

current_date=datetime.date.today() #Getting Today Date
sunset_time=datetime.datetime.strptime(sunset_time_str,'%I:%M:%S %p') #Converting String time to datetime object so that we can compar$
sunset_date_time=datetime.datetime.combine(current_date,sunset_time.time()) #Combine today date and time to single object
current_date_time=datetime.datetime.now()
stop_time = sunset_date_time + timedelta(hours=1) #This gives me the time of sunset + 1 hour
print (stop_time)
```

This prints the date and the sunset time + 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `import timedelta` and call

```
datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

instead.

You imported a module named "timedelta" and are trying to call that module, not a function of the module. I couldn't find a module named timedelta other than [the one in datetime](https://www.journaldev.com/23334/python-timedelta), though.

Comment: The link was what gave me the answer.  I had to change my imports